# C lists - Accessing a member of a struct and printing it

Tags: c, list, struct, nodes

I'm having some trouble with lists in C.

I made this struct:

```
typedef struct str {
char * str;
struct str * prox;
struct str * ant;
} cadena;
```

Then in the main I start the list with its first pointer to NULL.

```
cadena * lista = NULL;
```

Then I made a function where the user can add new elements to the lists (strings in the "str" member) and I manage the pointers to build the list. That seems to work OK. I hope.

But when I want to print a member of one node, it I'm trying to use something like this, and its not working:

```
void showdata (cadena *lista) {
    int i=0;
    while (lista.str[i] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c\n",str[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
from line "while (lista.str[i] != '\0')"
.error: request for member ‘str’ in something not a structure or union
```

(why is it expecting a structure? I thought I'm accessing a member there)

```
from line "printf("%c\n",str[i]);"     
.error: ‘str’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

(isn't it declared with the struct?)

I'm surely doing something really wrong, but I cannot understand which is the right way to access a char member and print it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pointer notation problem. C can be confusing in this way.

`lista.str[i]`

doesn't work because C doesn't recognize the "." as moving to a field. This can be a problem for people like myself who were used to C# or other OOP languages, where you can use the "." to modify properties of an object, like

`control.visibility = "False"`

In C, structs are based on pointers, so you need to use the -> like Keith said. You're *pointing* to a location in memory, or the "location" in the struct where a certain field is. Think of it that way, and you shouldn't have too many problems.

C also allows you to use the "."... but only if you strongly type the reference. For you, that would mean going

`(*lista).str[i]`

so that your reference to the lista instance is seen as a pointer to the struct.

So, in review, either

`lista->str[i]`

or

`(*lista).str[i]`

*should* work.

Comment: I was about to make a comment here and leave the first correct answer as solution.  But I needed to change the best answer to this one. You are right just as the first answer (thank you all!!) but you also left a lot of helpful information about it. Like how to use the "dot" in this case. Thank you so much. Managing lists in C is SO hard to me, because I cannot clearly "see" what's happening. And because I just started programming in C, this year in the University.

Answer (score 1):

```
lista.str[i]
```

should be

```
lista->str[i]
```

anywhere you have a pointer to a struct you use ->  not .

Comment: Thank you. That worked. But I have segmentation fault while printing the member.

Comment: probablly not allocating memory for your nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
while (lista->str[i] != '\0')
    printf("%c\n",lista->str[i++]);
```

Comment: Thank you. Using that way I get linker errors. Starting with << In function `_fini': (.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'>>, lots of lines from "multiple definitions errors" and then ending with the << collect2: ld returned 1 exit status >>.

Comment: @LeanDroid has nothing to do with your original question. But at least we got you past the compilation problem.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was making a mistake while compiling. But I receive segmentation fault while trying to print the member.

Comment: @LeanDroid that is likely because the pointer is NULL or invalid when entering the function. A different issue, but at least your making progress. At least now that you can compile and run, you can debug and find the run-time problems.